# Office excel add-in is getting cropped when loaded in excel online and in excel Desktop

Tags: office-js

I have an Excel office Addin developed using office.js, when that addin is loaded in excel online or excel desktop on some machine its getting cropped.
Please find the image below, notice that scroll head box at the bottom is not visible.Because of this the pop up message, i show is cropped.

[image]

When its all good, bottom scroll head box is visible

[image]

I belive its an issue from office framework nothing to do with the way office addin is developed. Let me know if anybody knows the solution for it.